# DB2 Defining remote database alias

Tags: db2, remote

I'm using DB2 9.7.0.3 for AIX.

I want to select data from a remote database, also running  DB2 9.7.0.3 for AIX, and insert it into the local database I'm connected to.

I believe the query for this is

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE 
    SELECT * FROM REMOTEDB.SCHEMA.TABLE
```

How do I define REMOTEDB as an alias to a remote database connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to catalog the remote instance.

```
db2 catalog tcpip node <my alias node name> remote <host or host alias name> server <port>
```

Issue `db2 terminate` to make sure the catalog entry remains.

Now you can actually catalog the remote database.

```
db2 catalog db <remote database name> as <local alias> at node <node alias supplied above>
```

And once again issue `db2 terminate`

Here is an example of what this could look like:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node devinst1 remote devservera server 50100;
db2 terminate;
db2 catalog db crmdb as remotedb at node devinst1;
db2 terminate;
```

Now you can connect to that local database using either the db name (crmdb) or the alias name (remotedb) depending on your needs.

Note: Sometimes you can run into issues where it will say things about a null package id. This would mean that particular packages need to be bound for the connection to work. Easiest way to solve this is to have your instance owner id (of the remote database) make the first connection and then disconnect or to have your id you are using have `BINDADD` authority. Then the correct packages will get bound. You may not run into this, especially if you are on the same version and fix pack level of DB. If you ever differ between "client" and "server" is when you for sure have to do this.

Comment: Cataloging the remote database works fine. However, trying to access tables in the remote database while connected to the local one results in this error: SQL0204N "REMOTEDB.SCHEMA.TABLE" Running db2 connect to REMOTEDB doesnt give any response.

Comment: Ok....then I think you are getting into federation. Which edition of DB2 do you have? Enterprise Server Edition?

Comment: @GabrielR. - by marking this the answer, I am assuming you didn't need federation then?

Comment: We ended up using a different solution to our data transfer problem. We have many tables to transfer, some with a very large amount of data. So we did a export to ixf of the source database, followed by a ftp transfer of the ixf files, followed by a load into the target database.

Comment: Makes sense. We do very similar for large transfers and are mostly using federation for stored procedures that need to access the data in two different databases.