# Add a DB2 catalog to a new remote server and make it work

Tags: db2

I'm trying to add a new database catalog to my client environment in a windows server machine.

So I've run the `db2cmd` tool and then the `db2` tool on a windows command console once there I executed the command:

```
db2 => list db directory

 System Database Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 2

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = DB01
 Database name                        = DB01
 Node name                            = DB01
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Remote
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =

Database 2 entry:

 Database alias                       = DB02
 Database name                        = DB02
 Node name                            = DB02
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Remote
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

Then I add a new catalog following the [docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.client.doc/doc/t0005621.html):

```
db2 => catalog tcpip node DB03 remote ***.***.***.*** server *****
DB20000I The CATALOG TCPIP NODE command completed successfully.
DB21056W The directory changes may not take effect until the directory cache is
updated.
```

After that I run `list db directory` again and the result was the same as previous one. I then, run the command:

```
 db2 => list node directory

  Node Directory
  Number of entries in the directory = 3

 Node 1 entry:
  Node name                      = DB01
  Comment                        =
  Directory entry type           = LOCAL
  Protocol                       = TCPIP
  Hostname                       = ***.***.***.***
  Service name                   = *****

 Node 2 entry:
  Node name                      = DB02
  Comment                        =
  Directory entry type           = LOCAL
  Protocol                       = TCPIP
  Hostname                       = ***.***.***.***
  Service name                   = *****

 Node 3 entry:
  Node name                      = DB03
  Comment                        =
  Directory entry type           = LOCAL
  Protocol                       = TCPIP
  Hostname                       = ***.***.***.***
  Service name                   = *****
```

So the node was created but it didn't show on the directory list, looking through the docs it says that I should run the `terminate` command

> Notice:
>   The command terminate is needed to refresh the directory cache.

Then it leave the db2 terminal and then I entered it again run the `list db directory` and again nothing changed.

So, my question is: **How do I refresh the database directory**??

I'm new to DB2. I have a lot experience with Oracle and what I could understand that this configuration is like adding a new entrance on the the `tnsnames.ora` file

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/db2-defining-remote-database-alias/29930#29930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node directory and database directory are different things. The node directory lists DB2 instances. The database directory lists databases in those instances.

Once you have added a node to the node directory, you will need to catalog a database on that node:

```
catalog db yourdb at node db03
```